# Test for no selection without a definition query

Tags: arcpy, select

I am trying to put together a little python script to check for whether there is a selection. The dataset I have is not robust enough to have an definition query on it, so I want it to just check whether there is a selection. arcpy.GetCount_management does this, and when I use the Describe function it does this too, but whenever I don't have a selection it is giving me the total number of rows in the dataset. From what I've read in the literature, the Describe function at least should return a zero value, because none are selected. Can anyone tell me why I can never get a zero value from either of these tools?

This is the piece of code I've been playing with most recently

```
len(arcpy.Describe("Footpath_centreline_Layer").FIDSet.split(';'))
```

so when I have nothing selected, 0 out of 16 records - I get a return of 16, and I need for it to be 0. I'm not sure how to achieve this, given my very limited python knowledge.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/73173/8104

Comment: What happens when you print that? What value do you get?

Comment: Also related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86120/checking-whether-feature-class-has-selection-using-arcpy

Answer (score 4):

[FIDSet](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/layer-properties.htm) returns an empty string if nothing is selected.

`split`ting an empty string returns a list containing one element - and the element is an empty [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)!

> If sep is specified as any string, the result will be a list
>   containing one element which is an empty string.

So, you need to first check to see if if `len` FIDSet is > 0 before splitting it.

Comment: I'm rather limited in my python knowledge...do you mean if I try 'arcpy.Describe("Footpath_centreline_Layer").FIDSet' ? When I did this I got 'u'1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 15; 16'' and there are only 16 lines in the layer. Are you able to explain more please?

Comment: That would indicate there are 16 features currently selected in your layer. If you click the "clear selection" button and run it again you should get `u''`, indicating that nothing is selected.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice walk-through of what you're trying to do here:
http://joelmccune.com/get-layer-selected-feature-count-using-python/

As mentioned by Joel at his website, another way to get an integer count of selected records is to use `arcpy.GetCount_management(myfeatureclass)`, as explained by Esri:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-count.htm

Something like:

```
result = arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrfile)
count = int(result.getOutput(0))
```

This will return the number of records in the whole dataset if nothing is selected, though. So, as @Kirk said, to check whether there's a selection at all, check whether `len(FIDSet) > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`layer.GetSelectionSet()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm#M1_GUID-A1071A05-599A-4662-8354-4F676BA87878)

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layerName = 'my_layer'
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, layerName)[0]

selCount = 0
if lyr.getSelectionSet(): # If there are selected features
    selCount = len(lyr.getSelectionSet())

print selCount # Print number of selected features
```

Printing `selCount` will return the number of selected features.  If there are no selected features it'll skip over the `if` and return a total of `0`